# Proximity-Relevance in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have an json record in the elastic search with fields

```
"streetName": "5 Street",
 "name": ["Shivam Apartments"]
```

I tried the below query but it does not return anything if I add streetName bool in the query

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": {
                            "match": {
                                "name": {
                                    "query": "shivam apartments",
                                    "minimum_should_match": "80%"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": {
                            "match": {
                                "streetName": {
                                    "query": "5 street",
                                    "minimum_should_match": "80%"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Document Mapping**

```
{
    "rabc_documents": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "autocomplete_analyzer",
                    "position_increment_gap": 0
                },
                "streetName": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add document mapping as well in the description ?

Comment: I tried the same using dynamic mapping and it worked for me. Chances are high, that your mapping is defined such that it will make this particular doc not searchable using the query u used.

Comment: @SahilGupta I have added the document mapping

Comment: @Gibbs .) N-Gram Tokenizer

 b.) Lowercase, asciifolding, trim, apostrophe & stopwords Token Filters

 c.) Html_strip Character Filters

Comment: @Gibbs Will that impact on streetName field clause?

Comment: Keywords fields are only searchable by their exact value - "https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html". StreetName is defined as a keyword in mapping, hence minimum_should_match may not work for that.
"5 street" is not searchable while "5 Street" is - and the reason is keyword mapping. Please try.

Comment: Thanks @Gibbs. I added my comment as an answer for clear visibly to other readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the E.S Documentation ([Keywords in Elastic Search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html))

- "Keyword fields are only searchable by their exact value".
- Along with that keywords are case sensitive as well.

**Taking aforementioned into account:**

1. Searching for "5 street" will not match "5 Street" ('s' vs 'S') on keyword field
2. **minimum_should_match** will not work on a keyword field.

**Suggestion:** For partial matches use "text" mapping instead of "keyword". Keywords are meant to be used for filtering, aggregation based on term, etc.

Comment: Normalizer also can be used.